# Passing int arguments in mbed::Callback

Tags: c, callback, mbed

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include <Callback.h>

InterruptIn up(p14);

void toggle1(int *player)
{
    printf("%d \n", *player);
}

int main()
{
    int player = 1;
    up.rise(callback(toggle1, &player));
}
```

In the mbed callback function, why the result is not 1? It is 12784.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowing your `main` function to return.  After it returns, `player` will be out of scope so it might be overwritten with something else.  In general, you never want to return from `main` in an embedded system, so I recommend adding `while (1) {}` at the end of your `main` function.

Also, using `callback` is a source of unnecessary complication and potential errors.  I would just put `player` in a global variable (and mark it as `volatile`).  Then you can simply do `up.read(&toggle1)`.

Comment: But I want to use &toggle1 in different buttons, which gives different values of ```player```. How can I do this?